# SOOOOO NEWB... Prolog Syntax Error: operator expected

Tags: prolog

I was trying to make a function that if one is negative, return the other.

```
foo(X,Y,F):- **X**<=0,F is Y.
foo(X,Y,F):- **Y**<=0,F is X.
```

is showing error... how to fix this?(** is the highlighted part)

Comment: Replace `<=` with `=<`.

Comment: Thank you! Finally solved it

Comment: Also, use `=` here, which is for general unification, instead of `is`, which is for evaluating arithmetic expressions.

Comment: Can you please edit the title into a more descriptive one?

Comment: @Dan: consider `foo(1+1,1-1,F)`

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says; `=<` not `<=`:

```
foo(X,Y,F):- X=<0, F is Y.
foo(X,Y,F):- Y=<0, F is X.
```

But a few more thoughts.

Rather than `is`, we can simply use identity:

```
foo(X,Y,F):- X=<0, F=Y.
foo(X,Y,F):- Y=<0, F=X.
```

Which has the advantage of working in more cases where not all variables are instantiated. Finally, it can also be written through pattern matching:

```
foo(X,F,F):- X=<0.
foo(F,Y,F):- Y=<0.
```